# Comparing Two Values when one or more could be NULL

Tags: postgresql, null

I am writing a trigger and want to see if one column has changed could be `NULL` and trying to avoid the following:

```
IF     NEW.value != OLD.value 
    OR (NEW.value IS NULL AND OLD.value IS NOT NULL) 
    OR (NEW.value IS NOT NULL AND OLD.value IS NULL) THEN
...
END IF;
```

This is postgres 9.5 in a function (stored procedure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equivalent and simpler:

```
IF  NEW.value IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.value  THEN
...
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately:

```
IF COALESCE(New.Value, -1) <> COALESCE(Old.Value, -1) THEN ...
END IF;
```

assuming that you know -1 won't appear as a value.

Comment: Actually i cant rule out -1 as a possible input.

Comment: In which case IS DISTINCT FROM is probably safer. Lucky Postgres users...